# Significant index of moderated mediation but no significant interactions of moderators

Tags: spss, mediation

I ran Hayes process Macro 8 in SPSS. In my results below, you'll see the index of moderated mediation is significant; however neither of the interactions in this model are significant. Model is below.
[image: Moderated Mediation Model] How do I make sense of this? Does this simply suggest that while paths a and c' do not depend on levels of moderator, the overall strength of the mediation relationship does in fact depend on the level of the moderator? Appreciate any thoughts.

[image: Index of moderated mediation]